# windowing for DICOM should use rescaleSlope and rescaleIntercept

Tags: xtk

How do I do DICOM windowing in XTK?  Just converting window width and center to WindowHigh and WindowLow doesn't produce the correct image.  Shouldn't the code use the rescale slope and rescale intercept tags from the DICOM header to calculate the pixel values?

Comment: Hi there and welcome to Stack Overflow! We would love to help you solve your problems, but it's very difficult to do that without a concrete example! Please update your post with some code that you can show us involving your question.

Comment: I found the fix for this.  Add rescale slope and intercept to the X.renderer2D.prototype.render_ function.  The calculation is   var _intensityTransformed = (_intensity * _volume._rescaleSlope + _volume._rescaleIntercept);

Comment: You should post that as an answer to your question :)

Answer (score 0):

As per the OP's comment, add rescale slope and intercept to the `X.renderer2D.prototype.render_` function. The calculation is:

```
var _intensityTransformed = (_intensity * _volume._rescaleSlope + _volume._rescaleIntercept);
```